# Show/Hide using toggle jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, show-hide, slidetoggle

**jQuery Script** 
This code works, But Is it possible to add 'options' inside the slideToggle method so that I toggle 'Show/Hide' text?

```
$(function() {
    var container  = $('div.container p'),
        button     = $('div#click');
    container.hide();
    button.on('click', function() {
        if (button.text() == 'Show') {
            button.text('Hide');
        } else {
            button.text('Show');
        }
        $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sachq/mt3duxzk/1/

Comment: Can you provide more details about what you wish to have help with? Your request is not real clear.

Comment: you can change the if statement to short version
button.text(button.text() == 'Show' ? 'Hide' : 'Show');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go ahead and give this a try. You may also change the "complete" option to "start" if you want the callback to fire as soon as you click the button.

**DEMO:** **[HERE'S A FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mt3duxzk/4/)**

```
    var container  = $('div.container p');
    var button     = $('div#click');

    container.hide();
    button.on('click', function(){
        container.slideToggle({
            duration: 200,
            complete: function(){
                var txt = (button.text() === 'Show') ? "Hide" : "Show";
                button.text(txt);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest better approach. The idea is that you should not hardcode your button texts into javascript code. It makes code very obtrusive and tightly coupled, because if you decide to change the text from "Show" to "Show more" you will have to modify javascript code as well. Instead you can have both labels in place but show only one at a time:

```
<div id="click"><span class="show">Show</span><span class="hide">Hide</span></div>
```

Javascript:

```
button.on('click', function () {
    button.toggleClass('hide');
    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
});
```

and CSS:

```
div#click > span {
    display: none;
}
div#click .show {
    display: inline-block;
}
div#click.hide .hide {
    display: inline-block;
}
div#click.hide .show {
    display: none;
}
```

---

UPD. Apparently someone disagrees with me. But it is easy to see that the benefits of slightly increased amount of code are bigger then it might look at first. Approach described above is much more flexible then comparing text strings. Not to mention it also allows advanced styling of the buttons with images and other elements which could be problematic with hardcoded strings.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mt3duxzk/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, but you can simplify things to ternary operator.

```
button.text(function(_, txt){
   return txt == "Show" ? "Hide" : "Show"
}).next().slideToggle(300);
```

Comment: don't need `$(this).text()` inside `text()` , second argument is the existing text

Comment: `.text(function(i, oldText) { return oldText === 'Show' ? 'Hide' : 'Show'})` would be better.

Comment: thanks. Wasn't sure if it was first or second and hence used `this`

Comment: You can use `is(':visible')` to determine state of toggled element, [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sachq/9yhrr8vv/1/)